# Login from a ViewController to a SplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, authentication, uisplitviewcontroller, segue

I'm writing a little app for consuming the results ob a webservice. The results are presented in a SplitViewController, on the left side the results and on the right side the details. Before getting the results, I ask the User to login via a login screen, which appears at first, whenever the app should start.

I managed the login process by changing the RootViewController of my application after the login is successful:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"LoginControllerSeque"] && [self doLogin]){
    TMAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TMAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    // IPad 
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)  {
        UISplitViewController *cvc = (UISplitViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:cvc];  
    } 
    // Other device
    else {
        UINavigationController *cvc = (UINavigationController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:cvc];  
    }  
    [appDelegate switchToMainView];
}
else{
    alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"access denied" message:@"access denied" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"back" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

I'm using a Storyboard segue for switching to the SplitViewController but it doesn't do anything without further actions.

In my AppDelegate there is the following Part:

```
- (void)switchToMainView{
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    TMMasterViewController *controller = (TMMasterViewController *)masterNavigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
} else {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    TMMasterViewController *controller = (TMMasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
}  

[self.window reloadInputViews]; 
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];}
```

So far everything is working but now I've got a logout Button in a PopoverView on the detailViewController of my SplitView, which follows the login screen. I thought I could do it the same way, so I made:

```
- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender {
[self.currentPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
TMAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TMAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[appDelegate.window setRootViewController:[appDelegate loginViewController]];  
[appDelegate switchToLoginView];
}
```

and in the AppDelegate:

```
- (void)switchToLoginView
{
[self.window reloadInputViews]; 
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Now if I try to log in the second time I get an error: **reason: '-[UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:]: Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.'**

Idon't have any idea, why this is working the first time, and the second time I'm getting these problems.

Can anyone help me or give me a hint ? Maybe it's the wrong concept for handling a login ?

**UPDATE:**

the problem appears exactly in this part:

```
  // Beim IPad müssen wir uns anders verhalten als beim Phone
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
    {
        UISplitViewController *cvc = (UISplitViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:cvc];  
    }
```

By stepping into the Line:
**[appDelegate.window setRootViewController:cvc];**

Comment: I'd look at who owns `currentPopover` and how you are instantiating it. The UIPopoverController class ref says "When initializing an instance of this class, you must provide the view controller that provides the content for the popover." Are you doing this? What happens if you call its `contentViewController` accessor? Does it produce a UIViewController as expected?

Comment: The popovers are defined in the storyboard by using a ViewController and a BarButton. The segue goes from the BarButton to the ViewContoller and is defined to appear as a popover. But I will check your idea, thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the same using a custom segue.  This seems to be have worked and much simpler.

```
@implementation LoginSegue
- (void) perform {
    NSLog(@"Do the segue you way");
    UIViewController *src = self.sourceViewController;
    UIWindow *window = src.view.window;
    [window addSubview:[self.destinationViewController view]];
    window.rootViewController = self.destinationViewController;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for similar answers:

I used the `UISplitViewController` `.preferredDisplayMode` property to create this same workflow: login screen to split screen master tableView on left, detailView on the right.

FWIW, I embedded nav controllers as the SplitViewController 'Master' and 'Detail,' and app only supports landscape orientation.

On app launch, the Master View (left) is whatever ViewController you want to show on the left after login. The Detail View (right) is the log-in screen. In the log-in ViewController `viewWillAppear` add (Swift)

```
self.splitScreenController?.preferredDisplayMode = .primaryHidden
```

This will present the log-in screen as a single screen view, rather than split screen. Upon successful log-in, present the Detail View Controller you want to display. In the `prepareForSegue` from the log-in VC, or `viewDidLoad` of the DetailVC, call

```
self.splitScreenController?.preferredDisplayMode = .automatic
```

to show the regular Master/Detail split screen. Or,

```
self.splitScreenController?.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
```

to force the split screen to show in portrait.

On user logout, I call `popToRootViewController` on both nav controllers to reset back to log in view.

Easy, no messing with windows or resetting root views.